# Fancybox 2 (on Mobile) How To Keep Fixed Position Inspite of Background Scroll?

Tags: jquery, mobile, scroll, modal-dialog, fancybox

Using Fancybox Version 2, and on the desktop/tablet, I could get the background page scroll to disable.

But that's not happening on mobiles (android). The background page scrolls, leaving fancybox modal at the top while the rest of the page shows the overlay.

So...

1) How to stop background page scroll on mobiles?

2) Or, how to make fancybox 'stick' to the viewport inspite of background scroll?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

*(Hits self on the head first for not reading documentation correctly!!)*

The solution for future idiots like me:

**autoCenter : true,**

Stays fixed on both mobile and desktop, to the center.